# Enable Windows 2008 R2 to accept cast on enum SslProtocols 3072

Tags: c#, tls1.2, sslstream

Enable cast (System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols)3072) on window server 2008 r2 without patch

I have a function written in c# framework 2.0 that performs authentication by setting the tls 1.2 protocol using an enum, on windows 10 and windows server 2012 works while on windows server 2008 R2 only works if updated with the latest patches. I need not to perform the updates, is there any registry key to enable the enum on the c# code that I report below?

the 2.0 and 4.5 .Net framework are installed on the server

```
SslStream sslStream;

sslStream = new SslStream(clientSocket.GetStream(), false, certificateValidator);

// Authenticate the server
try
{
    sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname,null,((System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols)3072), false);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

invalid value specified in 'SslProtocolType' enumeration

Comment: "I need not to perform the updates" WHY.

Comment: The servers are under a policy that does not update, do not have any internet connection. what I ask is if there is a registry key that validates the enumeration ... the tls.12 protocol works to send mail but does not read mails, remember that the framework used is 2.0

Comment: Simply adding a registry key isn't whats making it work.  I'm 99% sure the update include security updates to dlls and other items that allow it to work.

Comment: I enabled sending mail in tls1.2 simply adding a line in the registry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client & Server) I thought that even for this problem could be done

Comment: Running a 10+ year old unpatched operating system is a profoundly bad idea regardless of the circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the enum cast problem by installing the KB4471987 update (in detail on kb4470641).

Answer (score 0):

I've used

https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto

To enable and disable specific cipher on windows server. 
This will be a nice UI that will handle all the registery key for you.

Comment: This is indeed an excellent tool, but it doesn't answer the question **at all**.